# Facing error in trigger on Account Object

Tags: trigger, error, standard-objects

I wrote two triggers on Account object but since we should write 1trigger at one object at a time when am trying to add that with previous trigger it's throwing the error saying  -  **Missing '' at 'trigger'**

Can anyone please confirm what's cause of this error and how can I remove this error?

**Also attaching the code**

```java
trigger RecordDeletion on Account (before delete) {

    Id profileid=Userinfo.getProfileId();  
    profile profilname=[select Name from Profile where id=:profileid];
    for(Account accountDuplicate:Trigger.old){
        if(profilname.Name!='System Administrator'){
            accountDuplicate.addError('You do not have access for deletion. Kindly contact your Administrator');                                    
        }
    }
    
}
```

```java
trigger ParentFieldUpdate on Account (after insert, after update) {
    
    Set<Id> setOfParentId = new Set<Id>();
    for(Account pt : trigger.new){
        setOfParentId.add(pt.id);
    }
    
    List<Opportunity> listChild = new List<Opportunity>([Select Id, AccountId from Opportunity where AccountId in: setOfParentId]);
    List<Opportunity> updatedlistChild = new List<Opportunity>();
    for(Account pt : trigger.new){
        for(Opportunity ch : listChild){
            ch.City__c = pt.City__c;
            updatedlistChild.add(ch);
        }
    }
    if(updatedlistChild.size()>0){
        Update updatedlistChild;
    }
}
```

**Getting error at the start of ParentFieldUpdate trigger**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are just copy pasting both one trigger into another which is causing the issue.

Ideally you may need to merge the different trigger context as below.

```
trigger RecordDeletion on Account (before delete,after insert, after update) {
```

The later by using different context variables you need to include the logic in them as below.

```
 If(Trigger.isbefore && Trigger.isdelete)
    {

    Id profileid=Userinfo.getProfileId();  
    profile profilname=[select Name from Profile where id=:profileid]; 
    for(Account accountDuplicate:Trigger.old)
    { 
        if(profilname.Name!='System Administrator')
    { 
        accountDuplicate.addError('You do not have access for deletion. Kindly contact your Administrator');
    }
    
    }
    } 


IF(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate))
    {
    
    Set<Id> setOfParentId = new Set<Id>();
    for(Account pt : trigger.new){
        setOfParentId.add(pt.id);
    }
    
    List<Opportunity> listChild = new List<Opportunity>([Select Id, AccountId from Opportunity where AccountId in: setOfParentId]);
    List<Opportunity> updatedlistChild = new List<Opportunity>();
        for(Account pt : trigger.new){
            for(Opportunity ch : listChild){
                ch.City__c = pt.City__c;
                updatedlistChild.add(ch);
            }
        }
    if(updatedlistChild.size()>0){
        Update updatedlistChild;
    }
}
```

This should be your final version of trigger.

```
trigger RecordDeletion on Account (before delete,after insert, after update) {
    If(Trigger.isbefore && Trigger.isdelete)
    {

    Id profileid=Userinfo.getProfileId();  
    profile profilname=[select Name from Profile where id=:profileid]; 
    for(Account accountDuplicate:Trigger.old)
    { 
        if(profilname.Name!='System Administrator')
    { 
        accountDuplicate.addError('You do not have access for deletion. Kindly contact your Administrator');
    }
    
    }
    } 


IF(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate))
    {
    
    Set<Id> setOfParentId = new Set<Id>();
    for(Account pt : trigger.new){
        setOfParentId.add(pt.id);
    }
    
    List<Opportunity> listChild = new List<Opportunity>([Select Id, AccountId from Opportunity where AccountId in: setOfParentId]);
    List<Opportunity> updatedlistChild = new List<Opportunity>();
        for(Account pt : trigger.new){
            for(Opportunity ch : listChild){
                //ch.City__c = pt.City__c;
                updatedlistChild.add(ch);
            }
        }
    if(updatedlistChild.size()>0){
        Update updatedlistChild;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you but it's again showing the same error "IF(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)) " here




Error  Missing '<EOF>' at 'IF'

Comment: I hope an `}` is missing at the end as i have just said the process of implementing it. I have updated the final version of it

Comment: Thank you again